# Get specific string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I will briefly explain my issue:

I have a numbers looks like this: `971505896321;971505848963;971505478231;971509856987;`

My client should write the above numbers in a text field and I should take the `971505896321 and 971505848963 and 971505478231 and 971509856987` and add them into a list.

I success now to add the numbers to the list but I have difficulties how to get the numbers without `;`.

```
function AddPhoneNo()
{   
    var recipientNumber = document.smsmobile.mobile_no;
    var opt = "<option value='" + recipientNumber.value + "'>" + recipientNumber.value + "</option>"

    if  (recipientNumber.value != "")
    {
        if(verifyPhone(recipientNumber.value))
        {
             $('#selectedOptions').append(opt);


            recipientNumber.value = "";
        }
    }       
}
```

All the numbers should start with `971` and the length of each number is `12`. For example: `971506987456`.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Comment: use .split(";") function of javascript. e.g; var mobileNumberArray = recipientNumber.split(";");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace ; if I m getting you corretly than code for you is

```
var recipientNumber = document.smsmobile.mobile_no.replace(';','');
```

---

**EDIT**

if you are entering all number one than you need to split out your string

```
var recipientNumber = "971505896321;971505848963;971505478231;971509856987;";
var arrayofNumbers= recipientNumber.split(";"); 
var i; for (i = 0; i < arrayofNumbers.length; ++i)
{ 
   var opt = "<option value='" + arrayofNumbers[i]+ "'>" + arrayofNumbers[i]+ "</option>"

    if  (arrayofNumbers[i] != "")
    {
        if(verifyPhone(arrayofNumbers[i]))
        {
             $('#selectedOptions').append(opt);

        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this will add all the numbers without ';', I need to add each '12' digits as an item in the list

Answer (score 2):

```
var recipientNumber = "971505896321;971505848963;971505478231;971509856987;";
var mobileArr = recipientNumber.split(";");
```

and then u can run a loop on the above array and add those to your options